# Why is my code still showing wrong answer on URI?

Tags: java

So, i have been practicing using URI as i am a beginner i have been doing those simple questions but with this code i think i am getting the correct answer but still the site keeps showing wrong answer whenever i try to submit it.

So, the question goes on like this.

Read a value of floating point with two decimal places. This represents a monetary value. After this, calculate the smallest possible number of notes and coins on which the value can be decomposed. The considered notes are of 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2. The possible coins are of 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 and 0.01. Print the message “NOTAS:” followed by the list of notes and the message “MOEDAS:” followed by the list of coins.

Input
The input file contains a value of floating point N (0 ≤ N ≤ 1000000.00).

Output
Print the minimum quantity of banknotes and coins necessary to change the initial value, as the given example.

Input Sample
576.73

Output Sample

```
NOTAS:
5 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
3 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

Here is the code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
public class Main {
 private static DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        double a;
        int b[]={100,50,20,10,5,2};
        double c[]={1,0.5,0.25,0.1,0.05,0.01};
        int i,d;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        a=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("NOTAS:");
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            d=(int)(a/b[i]);
            System.out.println(d+" nota(s) de R$ "+df.format(b[i]));
            a=a%b[i];
        }
        System.out.println("MOEDAS:");
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            int e=(int)(a/c[i]);
            System.out.println(e+" moeda(s) de R$ "+df.format(c[i]));
            a=a%c[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I included the whole question. It displays the expected output too.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok, the issue that I found is this -**

The double precision modulo results are possibly making the end result bad. For example, `0.73 % 0.50 = 0.22999999999999998`, where I'd have expected 0.23

**Possible solution -**

*Correcting those weird modulos replacing the following line -*

```
a=a%c[i];
```

with

```
a=Double.parseDouble(df.format(a%c[i]));
```

This rounds the `0.22999...` thing value to `0.23`.

You can confirm different results from changing the above code statement before and after on `0.73` case. You'll find that the before version gives `2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01` vs the after version with the correct `3 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01`

Comment: The output i am getting is the same as expected one but the issue is site is still showing it wrong upon submission

Comment: @Codered Well, maybe there are other issues. I solved what I could find. Are you able to share something else, like an error or something, a failing test case? Otherwise, my only suspects are that it's not fit for some weird test cases, output is not in the correct format,  integer or double overflows. Could you provide link to the question maybe? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1021

Comment: Thanks bro, i tried it again and found that the problem was what u mentioned earlier.

Comment: You are welcome brother. Sorry, I almost forgot in work'n stuff, and didn't get to create account and trying submission for myself, but glad to hear your problem is solved @Codered